# angularjs isolated scope expression not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

Long story short my isolated scope is working for "=" binding not for "&" expression

here is my code so far

In controller

```
$scope.goToPage = function (pageNo) {              

        console.log(pageNo);
    };
```

In directive

```
scope: {
            'pagination': '=paginate',
            'paginateTo' : '&clickAction'
        },
```

The directive

```
<pagination paginate="pagination" click-action="goToPage(pageNo)"></pagination>
```

The directive View

```
<a class="button button-small" ng-click="paginateTo({ pageNo : 2 })"> Click ME</a>
```

Nothing happens.
If i remove the isolated scope and change the code. It works fine.
the binding is working pretty well so i didn't paste it here.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong ???

Comment: Can you create a plunker to demonstrate the error you are receiving

Comment: there is no error in console. I get nothing.
nothing happens :(

Comment: works fine with your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/vli4CMiJvjKl7grDg85V?p=preview

Comment: Now this is really weird. I am not understanding why it is not working in mine.
this is from a ionic project.

Comment: what i am doing is adding the elements through jqlite. So is this the problem ????
newElement.append('<a class="button button-small" ..........');

Comment: SOLVED IT. I was dynamically adding the elements to the directive. So now i first compiled the element in current scope before appending them.
.append($compile('.....')(scope))